# Система оповещения для DB mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Дано:
В локальной сети работает сайт, на PHP+MySQL, пользователь (редактор) вносит в него задания для других пользователей, которые это всё могут видеть по сети, через сайт.
Но вот хотелось бы усовершенствовать это дело и написать что-то типа агента-оповещателя на для новых записей для пользователя.

---

Думаю взять Delphi (набросать приложение) и им, от каждого пользователя, прицепляться к БД и оповещать.
Я правильно понимаю? (Прежде ни когда не писал связку web-приложение + win приложение).
Или велосипед изобретаю и есть, допустим что-то на уровне API-приложений?

Comment: *web-приложение + win приложение* — скорее всего, такая связка излишня. тому, что вы описали, самое место в уже используемом web-приложении.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрю куда хочешь оповещать:

1. Прям на сайте: [Web Notifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/) или [parse](https://www.parse.com/docs/)
2. На мыло: тот же сайт + cron + sendmail или Amazon SES
3. Висящая в трее прога - ну тут писать отдельно, для пушей взял бы [parse](https://www.parse.com/docs/) ну и как базу его можно юзать (ну мне кажется это не лучший вариант).

Answer (score 0):

я б предложил *websocket*, как более распространённое и имеющее больше возможностей.

Comment: у вас есть опыт разработки "оповещателя"(я так понимаю - это broadcast-pusher) на websocket?

Comment: @boris_U Да. На java. Могу помочь . Клиент может быть браузер или андроид.

Comment: я пытаюсь сделать на golang именно-что оповещаетель о событиях и не могу определиться с логикой этого приложения. Здесь есть функция личных сообщений? или может почта, скайп?